# VB6 client application which talks to one or multiple servers

Tags: sockets, tcp, vb6, sleep

I have a VB6 client application, which creates 1 or more (upto 4) sockets and connects to one or more TCP servers.

The client is supposed to continuously send requests to the server and wait for the server to respond for a certain responseTime. If the response does not arrive in the "responseTime", the client should send the next request on one of the sockets.

What is best way to make the client wait till the response arrives on the socket?

I do the following to have the client wait for the response/data to arrive: (Here the dataProcessed flag is set to True by the helper function invoked from the dataArrival() routine. This flag indicates that a response has been received and processed.

```
 *Do While ((Timer < SentRequestTime) + responseTimeout) And (dataProcessed = False))

     'DoEvents OR Sleep
     Sleep 50
 End If
Loop*
```

1. If I use "DoEvents" in the while loop, the application works fine for a while but later even though the response comes back to TCP layer (which I have examined through wireshark), the application does not get the DataArrival event.
2. If I use "sleep", the dataArrival event does not get delivered during the while loop, but arrives as soon as the loop is over. Using sleep makes the application non responsive.

What is the best way to have a single threaded VB6 socket client application to send a request, "wait for the data " to arrive for a certain time and then move on to the next request?

Answer (score 1):

I would forget about both `DoEvents()` and `Sleep()` here.  Those are tools of last resort, and nearly no program should contain either one.  You need to "think 4th dimensionally" i.e. "Trust the Events, Luke!"  This ain't your daddy's QBasic.

Here's a simulation where four Command buttons act as the servers, i.e. you click them manually as they become enabled.  Two Timer controls are used here because we need to simulate processing time and transmission delay.

```
Option Explicit

'Use 4 Command buttons to simulate TCP sockets making server
'requests and getting back responses.  Each "send" must get
'a response within RESPONSE_TIME_MS or be counted as a "miss."
'A new request is sent in either case.

Private Const PROCESS_TIME_MS As Long = 2000
Private Const PROCESS_TICKS As Long = PROCESS_TIME_MS \ 10
Private Const PROCESS_TICK_MS As Long = PROCESS_TIME_MS \ PROCESS_TICKS

Private Const RESPONSE_TIME_MS As Long = 4000
Private Const RESPONSE_TICKS As Long = RESPONSE_TIME_MS \ 10
Private Const RESPONSE_TICK_MS As Long = RESPONSE_TIME_MS \ RESPONSE_TICKS

Private ProcessCountdowns(0 To 3)
Private ResponseCountdowns(0 To 3)
Private Misses(0 To 3)

Private Sub SendRequest(ByVal Socket As Integer)
    ResponseCountdowns(Socket) = RESPONSE_TICKS
    cmdResponse(Socket).Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdResponse_Click(Index As Integer)
    'This is a "DataArrival" event.

    'Process the response, then send a new request:
    cmdResponse(Index).Enabled = False
    ResponseCountdowns(Index) = 0
    ProcessCountdowns(Index) = PROCESS_TICKS
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim Socket As Integer

    For Socket = 0 To 3
        SendRequest Socket
    Next
    tmrProcess.Interval = PROCESS_TICK_MS
    tmrProcess.Enabled = True
    tmrResponse.Interval = RESPONSE_TICK_MS
    tmrResponse.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub tmrProcess_Timer()
    'This just simulates delay involved in processing responses and
    'then sending new ones.
    Dim Socket As Integer

    For Socket = 0 To 3
        If ProcessCountdowns(Socket) > 0 Then
            ProcessCountdowns(Socket) = ProcessCountdowns(Socket) - 1
            If ProcessCountdowns(Socket) <= 0 Then
                SendRequest Socket
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub tmrResponse_Timer()
    Dim Socket As Integer

    For Socket = 0 To 3
        If ResponseCountdowns(Socket) > 0 Then
            ResponseCountdowns(Socket) = ResponseCountdowns(Socket) - 1
            If ResponseCountdowns(Socket) <= 0 Then
                Misses(Socket) = Misses(Socket) + 1
                lblMisses(Socket).Caption = CStr(Misses(Socket))
                SendRequest Socket
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Running the simulation requires two control arrays: one of 4 Command buttons and one of 4 Labels.  Then it becomes a game of "Whack a Mole."

Pretty routine stuff actually, and the main reason we have Timer controls in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob77!! I have got it running in a simulation program. Let me check it in the application.